# Animate angular flex-layout stretch

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Is it possible to animate the flex-layout stretching when it changes it's height/width?
For example, if I have an `*ngFor` in one of the flex boxes and I add new item or if I have an `*ngIf` on one of the boxes like these two examples:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
  <div class="base-card mat-elevation-z2" fxFlex="50%">
    <div class="content">
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="someInput" placeholder="This is an input"/>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="someOtherInput" placeholder="This is another input"/>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="base-card mat-elevation-z2" fxFlex="50%">
    <div class="content">
      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="item.prop" placeholder="ngFor input"/>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="item.name" placeholder="ngFor input 2"/>
        </md-input-container>
        <button md-icon-button (click)="addItem()">
          <md-icon>add</md-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the `addItem()` button a new item gets added to the ones in the `*ngFor` loop, both `fxFlex` elements grow, but without any animation so it just looks choppy.

Or something like this, using an `*ngIf`:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
  <div class="base-card mat-elevation-z2" fxFlex="50%">
    <div class="content">
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="someInput" placeholder="This is an input"/>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!isLoaded">Data loading...</div>
  <div class="base-card mat-elevation-z2" fxFlex="50%" *ngIf="isLoaded">
    <div class="content">
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="another" placeholder="ngIf input"/>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="andAnother" placeholder="ngIf input 2"/>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, as the first box has only one input field, it gets stretched when the `isLoaded` property changes from false to true, again with no animation, so it just snaps to its new height.

Is it possible to animate these changes when using `@angular/flex-layout`?

Comment: Yes , You can apply animation on that .

Comment: And what transition would I need to use to animate the flex height change?